# Associating LB private IP with a hostname /FQDN

Tags: cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

We have OKE cluster setup in place and as part of this we launched the private load balancer.

Now we are accessing this load balancer using private IP and its working fine.

But as per infosec team , we can not use direct IP to access the application, instead we need to assign hostname or fully qualified domain name to private load balancer IP to access the same.

Can someone advise how can this be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

When you initially create a VCN and subnets, you may specify DNS labels for each. Subnet DNS labels can only be set if the VCN itself is created with a DNS label. The labels, along with the parent domain of oraclevcn.com form the VCN domain name and subnet domain name:

VCN domain name: `<VCN DNS label>.oraclevcn.com`.
Subnet domain name: `<subnet DNS label>.<VCN DNS label>.oraclevcn.com`.
When you then launch an instance, you may assign a hostname. It's assigned to the VNIC that's automatically created during instance launch (that is, the primary VNIC). Along with the subnet domain name, the hostname forms the instance's fully qualified domain name (FQDN):

Instance FQDN: `<hostname>.<subnet DNS label>.<VCN DNS label>.oraclevcn.com`
For example: `database1.privatesubnet1.abccorpvcn1.oraclevcn.com`.

The FQDN resolves to the instance's private IP address. The Internet and VCN Resolver also enables reverse DNS lookup, which lets you determine the hostname corresponding to the private IP address.

If you add a secondary VNIC to an instance, you can specify a hostname. The resulting FQDN resolves to the VNIC's private IP address (that is, the primary private IP).

If you add a secondary private IP to a VNIC, you can specify a hostname. The resulting FQDN resolves to that private IP address.
Please refer this document, this might be useful [DNS Domains and Hostnames](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Concepts/dns.htm#DNS_in_Your_Virtual_Cloud_Network).